# Export to a file from SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run the export command in SQL Developer. I get the error message "Unknown Command". Searching the web, I am told by many to run `catexp.sql`. I don't have that file, and I don't know how to download it. Can anyone help me run this command? How do I find catexp.sql? Using the export functionality is not a feasible option since I must run the code below  about 80 times.

```
exp username/password direct = y file = C:\mypath\mydata.csv tables = TABLE.TABLENAME query =\"Where rownum\<=5000000\"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `exp` is a commandline program, not a SQL command. You cannot run that from within any SQL client (including SQL Developer)

Answer (score 1):

`exp` is a commandline program, not a SQL command.

You cannot run that from within any SQL client (including SQL Developer).

Additionally `exp` is somewhat deprecated anyway and you should use DataPump in order to export your data.

DataPump can be accessed through SQL using the `dbms_datapump` package and will write the dump file into a directory on the server.

`dbms_datapump` is documented extensively [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_datpmp.htm#i1007277)

There are also several examples available:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm
- http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_datapump.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to write a file on the server, I want to write the file to my hard drive. Will DataPump work for that?

Comment: @Clyde: no. DataPump can only write to the server

Comment: Okay. Thank you for responding to my question. I appreciate it. Enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a query in SQL Developer:

```
select /*csv*/ * from tableName
```

Then copy/paste the results to a new file.

This question [How to export query result to csv in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer) also has several other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really understand the syntax.

select C:\path\filename.csv * from tableName

returned an error.

I want SQL to write the file to the specified path on it's own. If I have to copy/paste that adds to the time I have to watch the program and when it finishes. I have 330M rows of data that I am trying to export, so the more automated the process is, the better.

Comment: That option doesn't quite help me. It's fundamentally the same as using the export function from the query, just that the data is formatted. I still have to export manually. Thanks anyway!