# seeing all the records of query and later importing them into a csv file

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle Sql Developer as a interface in which I am firing a query returning 85,000 rows of which only 58,000 approx rows are shown.

Can you guys please advise any way by which I can:

1. see all the records
2. export them (later) into a csv file

Please advise.

Comment: export to csv in order to transport the data or to do further analysis?

Comment: For exporting results to CSV you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/4169011 With regards the issue with not seeing all the records in SQL Developer, can you provide further information; what version of SQL Developer are you using, exactly what happens when you get to 58000 records etc

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer. Once you get the results -> right click on records select export -->Export wizard pops up then select format ( exp CSV), choose desitination where you want file to be stored then  click next and finish.