# Oracle - spool to CSV file, but Excel splits "$10,000" into two columns

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, delimiter

I have a command as follows:

```
SPOOL &&p_CSVfile

SELECT
  YEAR || ', ' ||
  TO_CHAR(AMOUNT, '$9,999,999,999.99')
FROM TABLE  

SPOOL OFF
```

...and values in the AMOUNT field can contain commas. When this file is opened in Microsoft Excel, the AMOUNT field is treated as two separate fields if it contains a comma. Is there a simple way around this that I am not aware of, or will I have to change my delimiter?

Comment: if you don't need comma separators for thousands, millions, etc. just replace the comma `REPLACE(Amount,',','')`, or wrap your value in quotes `'"' + Amount + '"'`

Comment: Spool just creates a text file. It doesn't wrap strings in quotes. You can use the Oracle utl_file package to control your output exactly, or use something like SQLDeveloper version 4 which has the "hint " /* csv*/ to delimit the csv output correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer?

Answer (score 3):

A CSV wraps each comma separated value in double quotes.  Are each of your values in double quotes?  If not,

Consider: (copy and paste below to notepad save as a csv)

```
"This is a","test"
"This is,a","test"
10,000,500
"$10,000","500"
"And she said, ""Hello my love""","end"
```

Lines 1,2,4,5 only result in 2 columns.  Line 3 results in 3.  Quotes matter.

[image]

So... To resolve add begin/end " to each of your values being output (what is " chr(34)?)

```
SELECT chr(34) || YEAR || chr(34) ||',' || 
       chr(34) || AMOUNT ||chr(34)
FROM TABLE
```

if your exported string data has quotes in it... simply double them up to escape properly.

Comment: Why would you use chr(34) instead of " " ?

Comment: Also, when I follow this method, I get the following error: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

Comment: sounds like some years and amounts or other values may be "NULL" and concat a null doesn't work.  need to coalesce(field,'') to put to a zero length string... though oracle

Comment: I'm currently working with a tiny data set and there are no nulls  =/

Comment: my example didn't have chr(34) before/after the comma I've updated.  wrapped SQL for readability.

Comment: We seem to be reinventing the wheel--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your value in double quotes `'"' || Amount || '"'`.

**Full Example**

```
SPOOL &&p_CSVfile

SELECT
  '"' || YEAR || '","' || AMOUNT || '"'
FROM TABLE  

SPOOL OFF
```

If you don't need commas in a specific field, you can also `REPLACE` them, i.e. `REPLACE(Amount,',','')`.

Comment: So the end users would manually have to format the column as currency?

Comment: Not in the first example, but the second example they would. Is your amount column a `money` type or a `string` type?

Comment: It is a number that is being converted with TO_CHAR - I have updated my question to include this detail.

Comment: Okay, I was just getting at design principal is all. I'll update my answer to exclude the additional information based on my assumption of `string` being the column type.

Comment: I do need the commas, so I'm not using REPLACE(). I'm still getting the same issue. Hmmm. I may just have to change my delimiter.