# how to copy the records from output of oracle SQL developer to excel sheet

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got some records from **Oracle SQL developer** & in the **output query result**. I want to copy the data & paste into the **Excel** sheet. How to copy the records from output of **oracle SQL developer** to **Excel** sheet.

Comment: simple google would give you what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Please see the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, select all the records from the **output query result** and copied it by using **Ctrl+C** then after open new **DataBase File** on *top left side* of the **Oracle SQL developer**. Then after *paste* all the data there into that **DataBase File**. Again *copied* the data from that **DataBase files** using **Ctrl+C** & paste it into the **Excel Sheet**.

Comment: When I do this, if I have fields with value of NULL instead of leaving a blank cell it just skips a cell.  So for instance if field1 is 'Oracle', field2 in NULL, and field3 is 500.  When I paste into excel instead of A1 'Oracle', B1 Blank, C1 500, I get A1 'Oracle', B1 500.  How do Ii get Excel to recognize a Null value as a blank cell?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand, accepted answer will get you results w/out headers. You can use right-click on results -> `export` there use clipboard as `save-as`, `format` -> delimited and the trick - delimiter to TAB (at least with tab paste works properly for my Excel version, default comma does not).

Answer (score 0):

Click on a cell in the output query results column and then press Ctrl + A to select all the records from the output query results. Then, press Shift+Ctrl+C to copy all the data and now go to your excel sheet and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select All in Query result section -> Right click and click on "Export..."
2. Select format as "excel 95-2003 (xls).
3. Change location where you want save excel dump file. Ex. C:\ from "Browse"
4. Click "Next" and "Finish" in export summary section.

[image]