# How do I copy and paste results from ORACLE SQL Developer to Excel while taking Null values into account?

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Googled this issue and have looked at previous Stackoverflow questions.  I am trying to figure out how to copy and paste from Oracle SQL Developer into Ms Excel.  I have tried right clicking my results and clicking Export and following the steps to Export to clipboard and I have also tried highlighting all rows and pressing Ctrl + Shift + C and pasting into Excel.  In both cases, when a field has a Null value in SQL Developer, it will just skip the cell in Excel.  For example if Field1 has a value of 'Oracle', Field2 has a value of Null, and Field3 has a value of 200, when I paste into Excel cell A2 (first row is headers) will have a value of 'Oracle', then B2 instead of being blank will have a value of 200.  How do I account for Null values when pasting?  The other issue is that I am working through Citrix so I am not able to easily save work from SQL Developer to my desktop (in fact it is damn near impossible).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807931/how-to-copy-the-records-from-output-of-oracle-sql-developer-to-excel-sheet) what you're looking for?

Comment: no, that is what I have tried but I am still having an issue with Null values being skipped as opposed to be left as empty cells

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're having trouble because I am not. True, I am not using the `Export` feature but you haven't said that you *must* use that feature. To continue the conversation in comments will be a bad idea.

First, I am using SQL Developer 19.2.1.247 and Excel 16.24 on macOS (but the OS should not matter).

Here is the query that I am using to test the copy & paste capability:

```
select 1, null, 2 from dual
union all
select null, 3, 4 from dual
union all
select 5, 6, null from dual
union all
select null, null, null from dual
```

If you reproduce good results with this query but bad results with your query, then I suggest you edit your post and include an [MCV example query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces bad results.

I select the query and press [Run Statement]. This creates a Query Result window that looks like this:

[image]

Then I put my cursor in the Query Result window and select all rows displayed by pressing Meta-A (⌘A or ^A) and then copy the selection by pressing Meta-C (⌘C or ^C). Then I see this:

[image]

Then I place my cursor in cell A1 in an Excel sheet and paste the clipboard by pressing Meta-V (⌘V or ^V). Then I see this:

[image]

Notice all four row's cells in the Excel sheet are correct w.r.t. the query. I did nothing special, not even invoking Menu->Data->Text to Columns. It was all done "automatically".

Comment: Since you're using the operating system's clipboard for the transfer, of course it matters that you're not using the same OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in the newest SQL developer [version 19.2](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldev/sqldev-relnotes-v192.html):

> A BUG with Excel exports containing NULL DATE values causes the Excel
>   file to be truncated, use CSV as a workaround or fall back to version
>   19.1